# Ruby one-liner syntax error on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

I am having a difficulty to spot where's the syntax error in my Ruby one-liner script.

Below Ruby script works on Linux

```
ruby -e 'File.open("blahnew", "w") { |f| f.write(File.read("blah")) }'
```

After I modified it slightly for Windows, I kept on getting this error message

```
C:\>ruby -e 'File.open("c:\testnew", "w") { |f| f.write(File.read("c:\test")) }'

'f' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone pin point where my syntax error please.

**SOLUTION**
The following ways will work

```
ruby -e "File.open('c:/testnew', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('c:/test.txt')) }"
ruby -e "File.open('c:\testnew', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('c:\test.txt')) }"
ruby -e "File.open('c:\\testnew', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('c:\\test.txt')) }"
```

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the quoting issue, you can use forward slashes on Windows. It's easier because otherwise you have to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you need double quotes `"` around your ruby script. Single quotes are not special to Windows, so it is interpreting the `|f` part as a pipe to `f`. You'd probably be OK if you switch your single quotes to doubles, and vice versa.

Comment: Your suggestion to replace all double quote to single quote and vice versa works.  Thank you